# CakePHP Migration Script doesn't update the Table Model

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, migration

I need to add an admin column to my user table in my database. I created the migration script with the following command.

```
bin/cake bake migration AddAdminToUsers admin:boolean
```

This mostly did what I wanted, I just changed the default value to `false`. My Migration script now looks like this.

```
<?php
use Migrations\AbstractMigration;

class AddAdminToUsers extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function change()
    {
        $table = $this->table('users');
        $table->addColumn('admin', 'boolean', [
            'default' => false,
            'null' => false
        ]);
        $table->update();
    }
}
```

Also, oddly enough, I've tried this several times and each time I'm only able to run this migration script once. I have to delete it and re-bake a new one if I want another one to work.

Comment: efficient and correct way would be NOT deleting the migration and creating a new migration with same table name to remove / make changes to the table

Comment: @prats1411 So each migration script can only be executed once? (Unless I'm doing a rollback I assume)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run a migration it marks as migrated and you can not run it one more time unless do the [rollback](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/migrations.html#rollback-reverting-migrations). Rollback will cancel previous migration and you will be able to run it one more time.Here is fully [docs](http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/) for plugin that cakphp using for migrations.

Comment: Is the migration script supposed to be updating the users Table Model, or strictly the database only?

Comment: strictly the database. You should re-bake model also, or change it by yourself after migration finished